# Concept explanation SPA (Single Page Application)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, typescript

I am working on an web application/site and I want to do it with `AngularJS`, `ASP.NET` and `Typescript`.

**I read about the Single Page Application concept, but I still have some question about this whole concept:**

1. Why should I prefer a SPA (Single Page Application) before multiple pages.

**I also have some questions about integrating it with `ASP.NET`:**

1. In `ASP.NET` it standard generate a nice `bootstrap` layout with about 3 pages at the top. So I think that it means that I need to combine all these pages to one page. But how can I get it to work together with the routing of `ASP.NET`. Because you will use the routing of `AngularJS`, and I want to keep the login from `ASP.NET` (*Can you maybe give an example so I can see how it works*).
2. If I got it correctly Typescript in this concept will replace the `JSON` webservice. Is this correct or do I got this all wrong?

If you could answer one of my questions I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPA's are a trend, they are mostly useful to move the load on your server to the clients. Only data requests will be made to the server, rendering is done on the client machine. 
There are still other benefits, but I guess this is the most relevant.

As to your questions regarding integration into ASP.NET.

1. Building an SPA does not mean all has to fit in one page. Look at AngularJS, it will fetch views as separate requests (see templateUrl in routingprovider). That being said, you can use ASP.NET MVC and serve ASP.NET Views as Angular Templates. This allows for a neat separation of Model, View and Controller parts.
2. Typescript is Microsoft's JavaScript dialect. It will not replace JSON and you will probably want to use JSON to exchange data with your server. You could use XML, but that is a little bit oldfashioned (and way more bulky).
   I have no experience with TypeScript so I would not consider doing that (coffee might be a better alternative), but there are also some quicks in JavaScript you need to be aware of. I would suggest  to search Douglas Crockford and Javascript on Youtube. The guy has great talks that can make you a JavaScript pro.

Comment: Re Typescript: If they are already using the MS stack (ASP.Net) then Typescript provides a language pre-compiler that lets you code your JavaScript objects more like C# (namespaces, interfaces, classes etc). It is also backward compatible so can accept raw JS. IMHO CoffeeScript will be a bit more alien to a C# coder.

Comment: Coffee will indeed be more "alien" for a C# coder but I guess coffee is more widely adopted than TS. Though I have no authority on either, I typically stick to JS.

Comment: Horses for courses. Having used both I find it easier moving between TypeScript and C#. The increase in productivity and ability to write more complex code in TypeScript (or CoffeeScript) makes either well worth learning. Writing raw JS, while useful to know how, is no longer the best option out there :>